# Visual Studio having conflict between referenced DLL's: only one is actually referenced

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce

While building my project, I get the message

> No way to resolve conflict between "System.Data.SqlServerCe,
>   Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" and
>   "System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91". Choosing "System.Data.SqlServerCe,
>   Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
>   arbitrarily. 33>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly
>   "System.Data.SqlServerCe, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" from Version "3.5.1.0"
>   [C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlServerCe\3.5.1.0__89845dcd8080cc91\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll]
>   to Version "4.0.0.1"
>   [...\bin\Debug\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll]
>   to solve conflict and get rid of warning.

The issue is, version 3.5.1.0 is not referenced in any part of the project. It is not in any `app.config` files. I can search inside Visual Studio or outside within Windows, for anything references that assembly, and it simply does not exist.

Comment: It's an indirect reference. It could be that you project reference a dll that reference a dll that references that dll for example. Also the dll referencing it does not have to be in the app bin folder it can be in GAC. This way it can be especially challenging to find

Comment: What @zespri says - try to add more logging to the build - also it is just a warning